# Can I mount a Novell NCP file system in Windows and use it like a standard lettered drive?

Tags: windows, filesystems, java, novell

If I have a Novell NCP file system can I mount it in Windows and use it as a lettered drive, e.g. G:\?

I'm trying to work out if an application based in Java, running on Apache Tomcat can access a NCP file system without having to install any additional APIs and recode any file IO classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mfinni, "this was one of the things that Netware was specifically made for."

This can be done using the Netware Client from Novell or depending on the vintage of your Novell fileserver, you can also serve up a fileshare using SMB instead of NCP and won't require the Netware client at all.

Once you have access to the fileserver, through either method it can be mapped as a drive or accessed as a network drive. For Java, I [Johnny Maelstrom] believe that using SMB or a mounted Windows drive letter is the best way to do this. As a standalone application you need to have access to the drive as a authorised user of the Novell fileserver. As a service the service logon needs to be an authorised user of the Novell fileserver.

Note: This answer combines information from mfinni, Canacourse, dsolimano and some of my own research.

Comment: It looks like you quoted part of my reply - it's a good idea to enclose that in "quote" tags, thanks.

Comment: good point, edits have been made

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using the Netware Client that Novell used to ship.  Typically users accessed their shares by having them mapped in their logon scripts, but you can certainly map additional drives using the standard Windows tools.

E.g., when you go to `Tools->Map Network Drive` in `My Computer`, you should be able to browse NDS and find the share you want to map.

Comment: Yup. In fact, this was one of the things that Netware was specifically made for. As @dsolimano said, the Netware client allows you to do this natively. Depending on the vintage of your Novell fileserver, you can also serve up a fileshare using SMB instead of NCP and won't require the Netware client at all.

The only complication is that this stuff is usually done at user login or manually, after login; is this application something that users run, or is it a service?

Comment: It's going to run as a service, so we'll login the service in as an appropriate user for the service to access all the content we need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you you are connecting to a volume on netware? Depending on what version of netware you are connecting too you might be able to access the volume using native file access which effectively mounts volumes / directory as a windows shares negating the need for the novell client.